# Is it necessary to explicitly free memory in Google App Engine's Python environment?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Is there a way to free memory in google's app engine?  Is there a garbage collector in python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python has it's own garbage collection so there's no need to release memory manually.

Answer (score 5):

Python itself managing the garbage collection. Normally, no need for manual memory release.

although, you can check [Python GC](http://docs.python.org/library/gc.html) lib, if you want to do it manually.